# Ajax code doesn't works in IE

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showState(str){
    if (str.length==0){ 
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else{
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            document.getElementById("state").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","getState.php?cid="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

This code doesn't works in IE but fine in mozilla and chrome

Comment: What doesn't work about it? Do you get an error? Do you get an unexpected result?

Comment: what version(s) of IE are you testing? (this is important!)

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Are you getting a javascript error? What do you see? What version of IE are you running this in? Also, I believe you should add "null" as an argument to the xmlhttp.send call - xmlhttp.send(null).

Comment: <td>Country</td>

 <td> <select onchange="showState(this.value)" id="country" name="country">

 <option>select</option>

 <?php

 $sql="select country_id,country_name from country";

 $res=mysql_query($sql);

 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))

 {

 echo "<option value=$row[country_id]>$row[country_name]</option>";
}?>

 </select></td>

Comment: @Ashitha: It's much better to edit your original question than put it in the comments here. Don't forget the error, if there is one. (In current versions of IE the developer tools - F12 - is pretty dang good.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call send(null) on the xmlhttp-Object.
Just add

```
xmlhttp.send(null);
```

This will actually send the request.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following:

```
function createXMLHttpRequest(){
    var xmlHttp = null;
    if(typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined"){
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if(typeof window.ActiveXObject != "undefined"){
        try {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.4.0");
        }
        catch(e){
            try {
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch(e){
                try {
                    xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                catch(e){
                    xmlHttp = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return xmlHttp;
}
```

source (http://robertnyman.com/2007/04/04/weird-xmlhttprequest-error-in-ie-just-one-call-allowed/)