# PHP Javascript AJAX fill and calculate several input fields - only one function fills?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, fill

I am trying to fill in a form using Javascript/ajax/php but the problem is that my function only fills in one of the needed forms and stops even tho I have gotten the second response from the server.

Code:

The function that starts filling stuff

```
function luePankkiviivakoodi(str) {
if (str==null) { //are we NOT injecting variables directly into the code, if not - Prompt for the barcode, and set the variable
    var str = prompt("Valmis vastaanottamaan", "");
}
if (str==null) { //someone pressed abort on the prompt, we return
    return;
}
newstr = str.split(' ').join(''); // remove spaces
if (str=="") { //is the string empty? -> return
    return;
}
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { //AJAX code
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        eval(xmlhttp.responseText);
        //we set some fields, no problem
        document.getElementById('P_VII').value = viite;
        document.getElementById('IBAN').value = saajatili;
        document.getElementById('laskun_summa').value = summa;
        document.getElementById('eräpäivä').value = eräpäivä;
        //trigger other functions
        getKassasumma(summa); //AJAX for accesing the database and calculating the sale price
        DevideIntoCells(); //AJAX for accessing the database and dividing a sum into different cells
        validateSumma(); //Validates the sum, and tells the user if it's OK
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","dataminer.php?question=pankkiviivakoodi&q="+newstr,true);//open AJAX connecttion
xmlhttp.send();//send stuff by AJAX
```

}

getKassasumma:

```
function getKassasumma(str) {
if (str=="") {
    return;
}
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        eval(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
kale = document.getElementById("TOS_K_ale").value;
xmlhttp.open("GET","dataminer.php?question=kassasumma&q="+str+"&kale="+kale.replace("%", "p")+"&nro="+document.getElementById("S_NRO").value,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

DevideIntoCells:

```
function DevideIntoCells() {
    str = document.getElementById('tiliöintitapa').value;
    if (str==null) {
            return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        document.getElementById("spinwheel3").style.visibility = "visible";
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        //alert('OK! val= '+xmlhttp.readyState);
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            //alert('OK!');
            eval(xmlhttp.responseText);
            //alert('OK2!');
            document.getElementById("spinwheel3").style.visibility = "hidden";
            //alert('OK3!');
            calculateSumma();
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","dataminer.php?question=percentages&q="+str+"&nro="+document.getElementById('S_NRO').value,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

validateSumma (just some math):

```
function validateSumma() {
    float = document.getElementById('summabox').value;
    float = float.replace(",",".");
    summa = parseFloat(float);
    if (summa < 0) {
        summa = 0
    };
    kassasummaunp = document.getElementById('laskun_summa').value;
    kassasummafloat = kassasummaunp.replace(",",".");
    kassasumma = parseFloat(kassasummafloat);
    if (kassasumma < 0) {
        kassasumma = 0
    };
    if (kassasumma == 0 || summa == 0) {
        prosentti = "0%";
    }
    else {
        prosentti = summa / kassasumma * 100;
        prosentti = Math.round(prosentti*Math.pow(10,2))/Math.pow(10,2);
        prosentti = prosentti+"%";
    };
    if (prosentti == "100%") {
        is100 = 1;
    }else {
        is100 = 0;
    }
    document.getElementById('prosentti').innerHTML = prosentti;
    if (is100 == 1) {
        document.getElementById('prosentti').setAttribute("style", "color:green");
    } else {
        document.getElementById('prosentti').setAttribute("style", "color:red");
    }
    puuttuvaEuro();
}
```

The problem code here is getKassasumma(summa); and DevideIntoCells();. I disable one of them, and the other one works, I enable both of them, DevideIntoCells stops somewhere before document.getElementById("spinwheel3").style.visibility = "hidden";, probably at the eval(response) because getKassasumma already finished the ajax request and killed this one. same the other way around.

AJAX answers: DevideIntoCells:

```
var KP_osuus = parseFloat('40');
laskunsumma = parseFloat(document.getElementById('laskun_summa').value);
onepercent = laskunsumma/100;
newvalue = onepercent*KP_osuus;
document.getElementById('box1.5').value = newvalue;
var KP_osuus = parseFloat('60');
laskunsumma = parseFloat(document.getElementById('laskun_summa').value);
onepercent = laskunsumma/100;
newvalue = onepercent*KP_osuus;
document.getElementById('box2.5').value = newvalue;
```

AJAX answer: getKassasumma

```
var kassasumma = '477.99€';
document.getElementById('kassasumma').value = kassasumma;
```

Please ask if you need clarification!

EDIT: Just to be clear, this is NOT an AJAX problem, rather javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to make `xmlhttp` local, i.e.

```
var xmlhttp;
```

Because you are overwriting you `xmlhttp` you refer to in the event listeners, so when the listeners get called, they both see the *same* response.

at the beginning of every of your functions. For compatibility, also use `send(null)` instead of `send()`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! However I can check through FireBug the responses, and I always get the desired ones, its just that the function stops executing when the other one is ready.

Comment: @Akke: of course, you get the two responses, but in both function `xmlhttp.responeText`  references the same text and gets `eval`ed double. So the execution do not stops, both start, but with the same text.

Comment: makes sense, I will implement your fix now ^^

Comment: No, place `xmlhttp.send(null)` everywhere where you had `xmlhttp.send()` and remove the `send(null)` from the beginning. Leave `var xmlhttp;` where you but it, it is ok.

Comment: quick question: What do I benifit from doing that `xmlhttp.send(null)` since this already works? Thanks a lot again!

Comment: If you call it without `null` you will get issues with older IE. See my answer [AJAX code doesn't work in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6678939/ajax-code-doesnt-works-in-ie/6678989)

Comment: Okay thanks for the heads up. I am however coding this for specifically firefox 3.0 or higher. Good to know anyway! Info cant hurt :D

Answer (score 1):

I think you are 'swimming in it', how we say. If you begin with AJAX, I'd recommend you use a framework like jQuery and it's `$.get()` or `$.post()` functions. It will accomplish all the needed AJAX logic for you.

Comment: Well the problem isn't AJAX here to my understanding as I do get the answers in the desired form 100% of the time.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, tho. Will try that out.

Comment: I mean, if you handle it low level using XMLHttpRequest, you have to care about many things, especially if there are more requests at the same time. Better to clean your head and let the jQuery to do the job. You just do the core of the logic, which is usually few lines of code.

Comment: I switched over to jQuery (Which is amazing) thanks for the tip!